# can't setState in a function inside a arrow function on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I'm trying to use `This` inside a function on a arrow function. How can I use `setState` inside my function?

```
showDeleteConfirm = commentId => {
    const { deleteComment } = this.props;
    const { comments } = this.state;
    // this exist
    confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure delete this?',
      okText: 'Yes',
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: 'No',
      onOk() {
        // this is undefined
        deleteComment(commentId);
        const targetPosition = _.findIndex(comments, item => {
          return item._id === commentId;
        });
        if (targetPosition !== -1) {
          // this is undefined
          console.log(this.state.comments);
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            comments: [
              ...prevState.comments.slice(0, targetPosition),
              ...prevState.comments.slice(targetPosition + 1)
            ]
          }));
        }
      },
      onCancel() {
        console.log('Cancel');
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: `this` is not defined on arrow functions. It goes straight to it's parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `this` in an arrow function just fine (method = () => {}), although using a method inside a class is encouraged (method() {}). The problem you are facing is not due using an arrow function but where and how you call it. The first part of the code works because you are calling it immediately. Whereas `onOK` and `onCancel` are at a later time and more importantly outside the context of `showDeleteConfirm`, where ever `onOK` is defined. Surely `onOK` will execute with its own this, not `showDeleteConfirm's` this. Here is a way to solve it:

```
showDeleteConfirm = commentId => {
    const { deleteComment } = this.props;
    const { comments } = this.state;

    confirm({
        title: 'Are you sure delete this?',
        okText: 'Yes',
        okType: 'danger',
        cancelText: 'No',
        onOk: this.onDeleteConfirm.bind(this, commentId),
        onCancel: this.onDeleteCancel.bind(this)
    });
};

onDeleteConfirm = (commentId) => {
    const { comments } = this.state;
    const targetPosition = comments.findIndex(item => item._id === commentId);

    this.props.deleteComment(commentId);

    if (targetPosition !== -1) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            comments: [
                ...prevState.comments.slice(0, targetPosition),
                ...prevState.comments.slice(targetPosition + 1)
            ]
        }));
    }
}

onDeleteCancel = () => {}
```

We bind the `this` to`onDeleteConfirm` and`onDeleteCancel`, so when they are eventually executed they get their this properly.You can read abound bind here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the `this` in an arrow function is always the same as the `this` in its surrounding block. Just use a regular function instead.

```
const showDeleteConfirm = function(commentId) {
```